# Access system trust store from Docker container

Tags: docker, truststore

in the past, i worked with c# and the .net framework 4.6. There I could directly access the trust stores of the windows system with commands like this:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(...);
...
```

Now I want to use .net core and run the application in a docker container.

I can use exactly the same code shown above, but i would see only the certificates that are somehow located inside the container.
I can add cetifidates to the store and read them back but when the container stops running the information is gone.
--> I guess this is because the store is only in memory valid as long as the container runs...

How could I use a trust store from the host system or from another container that is only responsible for managing certs and keys?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Are you storing the certs somewhere on the container ? if you want to keep the data even after destroying the container you need to mount a volume in docker. This will keep the data on the host and the volume itself can be shared with other containers

Comment: thanks. Then i guess it is important to understand where the trust stores are located on the system and mount a volume to that location in order to keep them persisted after the container stops running.

Comment: Should i submit this as an answer ?

Comment: partly i would say... my long term target is to use hardware Cert stores. So i really need to access for example a smartcard or a HSM module. Right now i have no idea how that can be done from within a container.